# Specifying "all odd values" in crontab?

Tags: cron

In crontab, I can use an asterisk to mean every value, or "*/2" to mean every even value.

Is there a way to specify every **odd** value? (Would something like "1+*/2" work?)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Depending on your version of cron, you should be able to do (for hours, say):

```
   1-23/2
```

Going by the EXTENSIONS section in the crontab(5) manpage:

```
   Ranges can include "steps", so "1-9/2" is the same as "1,3,5,7,9".
```

For a more portable solution, I suspect you just have to use the simple list:

```
   1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23
```

But it might be easier to wrap your command in a shell script that will immediately exit if it's not called in an odd minute.

Answer (score 84):

Every odd minute would be:

```
1-59/2 * * * *
```

Every even minute would be:

```
0-58/2 * * * *
```

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is almost 10 years old, but I was having trouble getting 1-23/2 for an every two hour, odd hour job.

For all you users where, *exact* odd hour precision is not needed. I did the following which suited my teams needs.

```
59 */2 * * *
```

Execute the job every two hours, at the 59th Minute.

Comment: this is a very nice approach

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
1-23/2
```

From your question, I'm assuming Vixie Cron.  I doubt this will work with any other cron.

Answer (score 3):

As I read the manual "1-23/2" (for hours) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Cronie
Even with 5 minutes interval e.g.

```
3-58/5 * * * * /home/test/bin/do_some_thing_every_five_minute
```