# Cron job every x hours from a particular time, perpetually

Tags: cron

Let's say I want my cron job to run every 7 hours, it would look like this: `0 */6 * * * foo`

But what I'd like to do is run it every 7 hours starting at a particular time.

If I want it to start at say *1am*, I know I can do something like `0 1,8,15,22 * * * foo`, but the issue is that this will reset the next day and start at 1 am.

What I'm looking for is a series like:

- 1am
- (+7) 8am
- (+7) 3pm
- (+7) 10pm
- (+7) 5am *on the next day*
- (+7) 12pm
- (+7) 7pm
- (+7) 2am *on the day after that*
- etc..

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/39004/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-run-cron-every-4-hours . Seems a right fit for your case.

Comment: The solution in that question does work, but only for time periods wholly divisible within the day. Since 24/4 = 6, this works, but it would not work for 7 hour periods.

Comment: How about this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122483/specifying-all-odd-values-in-crontab

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. You mean something like because 1/(24/7) ≈ 1 / 3.43 ≈ 0.29. So I could run it every 0.29th time of every 7 hour interval time right? I don't think Cron will understand that. I feel like I am over thinking this now lol.

Comment: It looks like you would need something like this which I'm author: https://github.com/Puchaczov/TQL.RDL, a post I made about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507109/evaluate-complex-time-patterns/43507110#43507110

I'm not sure if something like this exists for other languages however I'm working on something that should make it evnironment aware.